# get textbox value from ajax datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, onblur

can someone help regarding my problem getting the value of a textbox from ajax datatable? below is my code.

My controller:

```
public function getmovielist (Request $request, Response $response)
{
    $cart = Cart::where('category', 'action')->get();

    $output = [];

    foreach($cart as $c) {
        $output[] = [
            '<input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" id="movie_id" name="qty">',
            $c->title,
        ];
    }

    return $response->withJson(["data"=>$output]);
}
```

My JS script(load json response into my table)

```
var ct = $('#movie_table').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        url : 'getmovielist',
        type : 'GET'
    },
});
```

My View

```
+----------+----------+
| textbox  |John wick |
+----------+----------+
| textbox  |Deadpool  |
+----------+----------+
```

Here is my code to get the value of the textbox on blur

```
$('#movie_id').on('blur', function(){
    console.log(this.val());
});
```

but I got nothing in my console log. Thanks

Comment: In looping, you incluce `id` attribute for each of `input`. That won't work as `id` needs to be unique among every tag. Use `class` attribute instead.

Comment: ok let me try to change

Comment: @david still not working.

Comment: i just pointed out the error. my comment above doesn't mean to solve your problem.

Comment: ok thanks anyway for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use class selector rather id selector as id selector works for single element.

You can change your code like below and then try

```
    foreach($cart as $c) {
            $output[] = [
                '<input type="number" class="form-control txtmovie" min="0" id="movie_id" name="qty">',
                $c->title,
            ];
        }
-----------------------------
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.txtmovie').on('blur', function(){
        console.log(this.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: it works using this code `$('body').on('blur', '.movie_id', function() {
        console.log(this.value);
    });`

Comment: but don't know to pass arguments like the id and quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is wrong. I used `$('body')` because if you generate element dynamically with ajax, delegate events should be at the closest static element.

```
$('body').on('blur', '#movie_id', function(){
 console.log(this.val());
});
```